# How to sort Custom Fields by a value

Tags: custom-field

i use below code in home page for show a table of custom fields. but i don't know how sort this table by duration value.

```
<table>
<?php while(have_posts()): the_post() ; ?>
<?php if (get_post_meta($post->ID, 'duration', true)>'1') :  { ?>
<tr>    <?php global $wp_query; $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; ?>
    <td>    <?php echo get_post_meta($postid, 'target', true); ?> </td>
    <td>    <?php echo get_post_meta($postid, 'price', true); ?> </td>
    <td>    <?php echo get_post_meta($postid, 'duration', true); ?> </td>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?> </tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
   </table>
```

Comment: It's too late to sort at this point; you need to specify the sort parameters in your query. Here's a [similar issue](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_query-ordered-by-custom-field-value?replies=4).

Comment: Please post your query, if you want adequate help.

Answer (score 0):

If you need sorted result by default,you need to query with sort parameters
see https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters more more

(example from the codes)

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 'post_type' => 'product', 'orderby' => 'meta_value', 'meta_key' => 'price' ) );
```

Alternatively, you could also easily do the sorting using jquery plugins like tinysort
 ( see http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/ )

Hope this helps!